# Jsp pages open in Https and Http

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I am new to Java and using Tomcat.

I have configured Tomcat to run on https using this link
[source](https://dzone.com/articles/setting-ssl-tomcat-5-minutes)

I have only done changes to server.xml file in Tomcat directory.And change looks something like this.

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           keystoreFile="C:\Users\sanjithkumar017\Desktop\myKey.keystore" keystorePass="qwerty"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

and then i am able to access the url `https://localhost:8443` successfully.

I have created a war file(mserv) of my project and put it in webapps folder of tomcat.

The problem is When i hit it the url `https://localhost:8443/mserv/dis.jsp` i get the response(i mean it works).And also when i try `http://localhost:8080/mserv/dis.jsp` it works fine.

This is supposed to work like this.I want the jsp pages to run only on https.

And What i have done next is added a web.xml file to my eclipse project(cause i need some jsp pages in my project to run on http).The web.xml file looks something like this.

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>secured page</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/mserv/dis.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/mserv/index.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/mserv/pcr.jsp</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
```

So what i am expecting now is that only the pages mentioned above(application's web.xml) must be accessible on https.But still, i am able to access all the pages using both http and https.

I want my pages to be accessed only using https.

Where am i going wrong.Please help.

jdk::jdk1.7.0_79

tomcat::apache-tomcat-7.0.67

Comment: You will need to write a custom servlet filter or tomcat valve. I'll see if I can post some code later.

Answer (score 0):

Add filter in your project say HttpsFilter and use request object to find the whether request if https or not using isSecure() method. Following is the code :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class HttpsFilter implements Filter {

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public HttpsFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#destroy()
     */
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain)
     */
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // place your code here
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        if(!request.isSecure())
        {
            /* Here you can redirect to error page or do permanent redirection using resp object */
        }

        // pass the request along the filter chain
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#init(FilterConfig)
     */
    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

In web.xml, specify the URL pattern for which this filter need to applied

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>httpsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>HttpsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/mserv/dis.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/mserv/index.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/mserv/pcr.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```